# Get pixel values ascii 50 files

Tags: r, analysis

I'm working with photos from a camera. The camera is arranged to take NDVI values instead of RGB for each pixel. I have several folders with 50 pictures in each folder as '*.asc' files the pictures.

I am using R to automatize the process, the problem is that I can't find the best way. I want to get the information of the pixels in a region, a polygon. The same for all the pictures.

I have been opening a picture as reference with ArcGIS, I draw the polygon and save it. Then I bring it to R *(f(x) readshapePoly)* and they I try the function '*extract('*.asc*, polygon)* but I get several errors... I am new at this world also with R, and I don´t know where am I failing... I hope you can try to help me

Comment: Could you post the script you have been developing?  Also, what end product would you like to have (e.g. a dataframe containing the ID and values)?

Comment: Im trying to develop it. My idea is to get a dataframe containing the ID, values, hour and date. To export it to a DB